# Verilog: Concatenation with unsized literal, but why?

Tags: verilog, concatenation

My project finally compiles without errors, but the warnings are "hungry and numerous". For example, I have this line:

```
  i_temp_reg <= {{SPI_WIDTH{'b0}}, i_temp_reg[BANK_DATA_WIDTH-1:SPI_WIDTH]};
```

Where I have the parameters defined as:

```
  parameter SPI_WIDTH                   = 8;
  parameter BANK_DATA_WIDTH             = 32;
```

i_temp_reg is a register, as the name might suggest. I have several more statements like this (same format, different registers) and all of them get the error:

```
  Concatenation with unsized literal; will interpret as 32 bits
```

But I thought I pretty clearly specified the size of this literal (the 'b0). So what's going on, Verilog? I must say here that I use VHDL normally, and I'm fairly comfortable with it and this crazy language is driving me a bit insane. Did I mess up the sizing of this literal?

Secondly, and kind of related, I get another problem. Here are relevant statements and the warning:

```
 output     [BANK_SIZE-1:0]             wAddr;
 reg        [BANK_SIZE-1:0]             i_wAddr;

 assign w_Addr          = i_wAddr;

 Warning: Result of 4-bit expression is truncated to fit in 1-bit target.
```

If someone could help me with identifying what I'm doing wrong exactly, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 6):

`'b0` is indeed an unsized literal for the number zero, specified in binary.  If you want to specify the width it should prefix the literal.

```
1'b0      // single bit 0
1'b1      // single bit 1
4'b1001   // 4 bits, value = 9
```

In your code which is generating the warning you have:

```
{SPI_WIDTH{'b0}}
```

The syntax in use here is the *replication operator*, where `SPI_WIDTH` is the number of times to replicate `'b0`. Replication is a special case of concatenation, and because `'b0` is an unsized literal, you get the warning.

If you want to replicate a single bit `SPI_WIDTH` times, resulting in a vector of `SPI_WIDTH` bits, you need to size the inner value to a single bit, as Greg pointed out in the comments.

```
{SPI_WIDTH{1'b0}}
```

Comment: @Mewa, you want `{SPI_WIDTH{1'b0}}`. `1'b0`, not `'b0`

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your code with a shift register:

```
i_temp_reg <= i_temp_reg >> SPI_WIDTH;
```

This is more intuitive and scalable.